# Поиск элемента по тексту document.querySelector, какой селектор подобрать?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, эмулятор

Пытаюсь сделать эмуляцию клика, найдя элемент по тексту в нем. Как правильно написать селектор? Пробовал разные конструкции, наподобие этой:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let link = document.querySelector("//*[text()='Search FragmentX']"); 
  link.click(); 
});
```

outerHTML элемента

```
<label for="x-auto-1558" htmlfor="x-auto-1558" class="x-form-cb-label" style="position: relative; left: 0.78479px; top: -0.0104141px;">Search FragmentX</label>
```

Full XPath
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/label

Поиск по ID и прочим стандартным параметрам не вариант, так как они периодически меняются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не существует прямого селектора по тексту. Нужно придумывать костыль.

Поиск тупо среди всех элементов на странице запускается через селектор `*` → `document.querySelectorAll('*');` — Плохая идея, как минимум потому что если какой-то элемент содержит нужный текст, то и все его родители его включают. Помимо `*` - нужно будет искать конкретно `textNode` (nodeType == 3) среди всех childNodes каждого элемента.

Но хорошо, что примерно известно, где может попадаться искомый текст - можно взять все элементы с этим классом (или тегом - тег же не меняется) и отфильтровать по тексту:

```js
let lab = document.querySelectorAll('label');
[...lab].forEach( e => e.onclick = () => e.classList.add('bg') ); // Демо клика

/******************************************/

runAutoClicks();

function runAutoClicks(){
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.x-form-cb-label');
          // или  .querySelectorAll('label');

  x = Array.from( x ).filter( e => (/[mt]ake red/i).test( e.textContent ) );
  // Взяли все элементы с этим классом, отфильтровали по textContent

  let i = 0;  
  bubu();
  
  function bubu(){
    x[i].click();
    
    if( x[++i] ){ // - существует ли следующий элемент, заодно сразу увеличивает `i`
      setTimeout( bubu, 1000 );
      // Будет не хорошо, если пойдет одновременный клик по 10+ элементам.
    }
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

label.bg { background-color: #c00; color: white; }
```

```html
<label class="x-form-cb-label">make red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">take red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">fake red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">make red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">take red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">fake red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">make red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">take red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">fake red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">make red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">take red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">fake red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">make red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">take red</label>
<label class="x-form-cb-label">fake red</label>
```

См. «Регулярные Выражения» → http://learn.javascript.ru/

Но у событий существует свойство `isTrusted`. Если создатель сайта захочет - может защищаться от кликов через скрипт, запущенный в браузере:

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

[...test].forEach( (test, i) => {
  test.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    test.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      if( event.isTrusted ){
        test.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
        console.log(`Элемент номер ${i}, кликнул скрипт.`);
      }
    }, 500);
  });
});

test[0].click();
test[1].click();
```

```css
.test {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Попробовал адаптировать свой скрипт с вашим фильтром 
setTimeout(function() {
  let link = document.querySelectorAll('label'); 
  link = Array.from( link ).filter( e => (/Search FragmentX/i).test( e.textContent ) );
  link.click(); 
});
Не сработало, в чем ошибка?

А вот такой вариант прекрасно кликает на нужный мне элемент
setTimeout(function() {
  let link = document.querySelector("#x-auto-691");
  link.click();
});

Comment: @Vladislav `link.click();` — ошибка вот тут) link - это же не один конкретный элемент, а массив (даже если там один элемент - массив с одним элементом). Оттуда сначала нужно достать элемент, потом кликнуть... `link[1].click(); link[2].click();` — поэтому нужен какой-то цикл)

Comment: Сработало с link[0].click() 
Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

> `let link = document.querySelector("//*[text()='Search FragmentX']");`

Методы `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll` понимают только CSS-селекторы.
Для поиска по XPath, нужно использовать `document.evaluate`.

---

Вот маленькое расширение прототипа элемента, для регистронезависимого поиска по тексту:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.getNodesByText = function (text) {
  const expr = `.//*[text()[contains(
    translate(.,
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ',
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    ),
    '${text.toLowerCase()}'
  )]]`;    /* коммент-костыль */
  const nodeSet = document.evaluate(expr, this, null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null);
  return Array.from({ length: nodeSet.snapshotLength },
    (v, i) => nodeSet.snapshotItem(i)
  );
};

// использование
document.body.getNodesByText('fragment').forEach(
  el => el.style.backgroundColor = '#7f7'
);
```

```html
<label>Foo</label>
<label>Search FragmentX</label>
<label>Bar</label>
```

Возвращает массив нодов (или пустой массив, в случае когда ничего не найдено).

Вызывать этот метод можно только от элементов - вызов от `document` не сработает, так как последний не наследует `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Первый коммент в коде нужен для того чтобы подсветка синтаксиса в сниппете не сходила с ума, видя `/*` (считает это началом комментария).

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  let link = document.querySelectorAll('label'); //собираем все элементы label в nodelist
  link = Array.from( link ).filter( e => (/Текст/i).test( e.textContent ) ); //переводим в массив и фильтруем по тексту
  link[0].click();  //кликаем по первому элементу массива
});
```