# Поиск с фильтром через input

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

У меня есть 4 карточки с товаром `(card)`. Внутри контент с текстом, мне необходимо, чтобы при вводе в поле для поиска, карточки фильтровались и отображались на странице, либо же пропадали в соответствии с введенным значением в поле `input` и текстом в них(теги 'p'). Сделать это нужно без `доп.фреймворков(jquery,react и тд)`,только нативный `JS`. Нашел пример в интернете, выполненный с тегами `ul`, `li`, `a`. Сделал по примеру со своими тегами, но не работает - **ошибка**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

Насколько я понимаю, вся путаница в тегах происходит. Вот код-верстка одной из карточек(еще 3 дублировать не буду) и код `javascript`. Буду благодарен за помощь, либо же за свой предложенный вариант подобной фильтрации через `input`.

```js
let search = document.getElementById('search')

search.onkeyup = (event) => {
 
 
  let filter = search.value.toUpperCase();
  let card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  let cardBody = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body");
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    let p = cardBody[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if (p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      card[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      card[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <input id='search' type="search" placeholder="Search">

<div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem;">
    <div class='text-center py-4'>
    <img src="img/phone_one.png"style="width: 6.25rem;" class="card-img-top" alt="phone">
  </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between ">
      <p class="card-title position-relative">Huawei Mate S
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
   
    </div>
  
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2 mx-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: У вас же только четыре карточки, почему делаете итерацию по 15 элементам? Вы перебираете `card-body`, а не `card`, зачем? Ошибка возникает потому, что у вас есть второй `div.card-body` внутри `div.card`, который не содержит никаких тегов `p` - только `a`.

Comment: Все верно, разобрался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск элементов по их текстовому содержимому - это одна из проблемных задач, т.к. из стандартного инструментария, такой поиск "умеют" только [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)-селекторы.

Можно использовать перебор элементов, в каждом из них выполняя поиск подстроки средствами JS (строковыми методами / регулярками), но это *очень* неэффективно.

Поэтому, я предлагаю использовать именно XPath - через вспомогательный метод для текстового поиска элементов, взятый [из моего старого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049219/288409) (shameless plug ):

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.getNodesByText = function (text) {
  const expr = `.//*[text()[contains(
    translate(.,
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ',
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    ),
    '${text.toLowerCase()}'
  )]]`;    /**/
  const nodeSet = document.evaluate(expr, this, null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null);
  return Array.from({ length: nodeSet.snapshotLength },
    (v, i) => nodeSet.snapshotItem(i)
  );
};

// код решения начинается здесь
const allCards  = document.querySelectorAll('.card'),
      container = document.querySelector('.container');
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', evt => {
  allCards.forEach(card => card.classList.remove('search-result'));      // убираем класс, добавленный при предыдущем поиске
  const searchStr = container.dataset.search = evt.target.value.trim();  // заносим поисковую строку в data-атрибут, чтобы магия скрытия карточек в CSS работала
  if (!searchStr.length) return;
  for (const el of container.getNodesByText(searchStr)) {  // в цикле по найденным элементам...
    const card = el.closest('.card');                      // ...находим родительскую карточку элемента...
    if (card) card.classList.add('search-result');         // ...и добавляем ей класс со стилем "видимости"
  }
});
```

```css
[data-search]:not([data-search=""]) .card:not(.search-result) { display: none; }
.container    { padding: 0.5rem 0; }
.card         { padding: 0.5rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.card + .card { margin-top: -1px; }
.card img     { display: none; } /* картинки все равно "битые" из-за URL */
.card p       { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 24rem;">
    <div class='text-center py-4'>
      <img src="img/phone_one.png" style="width: 6.25rem;" class="card-img-top" alt="phone" </div>
      <div class="card-body text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between ">
        <p class="card-title position-relative">Huawei Mate S</p>
        <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2 mx-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="width: 24rem;">
    <div class='text-center py-4'>
      <img src="img/phone_one.png" style="width: 6.25rem;" class="card-img-top" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between ">
      <p class="card-title position-relative">Лень что-то придумывать, просто текст</p>
      <p class="card-text">$265.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2 mx-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="width: 24rem;">
    <div class='text-center py-4'>
      <img src="img/phone_one.png" style="width: 6.25rem;" class="card-img-top" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between ">
      <p class="card-title position-relative">Скрипту все равно пофигу какой текст искать</p>
      <p class="card-text">$148.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link border px-2 mx-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Чтобы комментарии в коде примера было удобнее читать, советую развернуть его на всю страницу.

Метод `getNodesByText` генерирует XPath-селектор поиска по тексту (чего CSS-селекторы не могут) с приведением к нижнему регистру. Затем с этим селектором выполняет выборку из документа, и заполняет ее содержимым массив. В принципе, объяснять там нечего - это просто бойлерплейт работы с `document.evaluate` спрятанный внутрь метода.

---

Разбор селектора "магического" CSS-правила скрытия карточек, если интересно:
`[data-search]:not([data-search=""])` == наличие непустого атрибута data-search
`.card:not(.search-result)` == элементы имеющие класс `card`, но не имеющие класса `search-result`
<sub>То есть, когда скрипт помещает строку поискового запроса в data-атрибут `search` контейнера, и удаляет класс `search-result` у всех карточек - все карточки скрываются. Сразу после этого, скрипт пробегает по карточкам найденных элементов, добавляя класс тем карточкам которые должны быть видны, и тем самым исключая их из попадания под CSS-селектор правила с `display: none`.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @den24, пожалуйста)) Метод `document.evaluate` поддерживается всеми популярными браузерами (IE в их число не входит), поэтому метод поиска из кода в ответе можно достаточно смело использовать. Для простых задач, в которых требуется обычный буквальный поиск подстроки, он вполне годится. Под более сложные - уже придется дорабатывать, конечно.