# Как найти строку на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно в скрипте узнать, есть ли просто на странице или в href ссылок фрагмент '{{getSetting'

Пробовал так, но видимо это не то, что нужно.

```
if (~$('body').text().indexOf('{{getSetting') || $('a').attr('href').indexOf('{{getSetting')) {
   
    console.log($('a').attr('href').indexOf('{{getSetting'))
    console.log(~$('body').text().indexOf('{{getSetting'))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете выполнить поиск по элементам с атрибутом `href`, значение которого содержит строку `{{getSetting`. Если "длина" коллекции элементов 0 - таких элементов нет, если больше - есть такие элементы на странице. Для поиска используется селектор атрибута, как в CSS.

Справка: [селекторы атрибутов в CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="{{getSetting"]');

console.log(links.length);
```

```html
<a href="{{getSetting"></a>
<a href="{{getSetting"></a>
<a href="{{getSetting"></a>
<a href="{{getSetting"></a>
<a href="{{getSetting"></a>
```

Для поиска строки внутри содержимого документа:

```js
document.querySelector('html').outerHTML.includes('{{getSetting');
```

Comment: А если просто во всем документе нужно найти этот фрагмент ? Как обычный текст

Comment: @Бармалей обновил ответ

Comment: @Бармалей, если элементы по тексту в их контенте искать, то [вот эта штука](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049219/288409) будет поэффективнее строкового поиска средствами JS с перебором всех элементов документа (хотя если ограничивать поиск небольшой веткой DOM, и перебор может устроить).